# Como mostrar a quantidade de visualizações de uma página

Tags: php, wordpress

Possuo a página [www.neilgaiman.com.br](http://www.neilgaiman.com.br), que foi desenvolvida com Wordpress. Gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de mostrar ao usuário, a quantidade de visualizações que a página que ele estiver, tem.

Pergunto aqui, pois não quero depender de plugin. Se possível, algo que pegue os dados direto do Google Analytics.

Comment: Acho que o que você quer está na [**DOC**](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreDevguide)

Comment: Obrigado. Soou um pouco complicado para mim, hehe. Acho que um plugin será o mais ideal.

Comment: Eu nunca implementei nada do tipo. O wp deve ter algum plugin de facil instalacao, mesmo que voce nao queira usa-lo, pode servir para estudar o code.

Comment: Um plugin que faça o que deseja não vai sacrificar em praticamente nada o desempenho do seu projeto, não mais que outros plugins que podem ser realmente desnecessários.

Comment: Essa história de "sem plugin" é totalmente despropositada. Vide [Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615) e [Questions specifically asking for a solution “without a plugin”](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1288/12615)

Comment: Vou ter que ler com mais atenção o link que você passou @brasofilo. Mas, estou optando por não usar plugins, para não ficar dependendo de terceiros. Em contar, que diversas invasões em sites com Wordpress, acontecem por meio de plugins.

Comment: OK, mas sua pergunta podia ser um pouco mais específica, porque estou vendo dois objetivos nela: 1) Quantidade de visualizações, você já usa GA, está procurando outra coisa? 2) Como integrar essa contagem no frontend, que é sua pergunta original, mas sem saber do `1)` me parece "ampla demais".

Comment: Ou você usa um plugin, ou você desenvolva um código pra isso. Acho totalmente invalida essa pergunta.